# Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance. When i call the API

Tags: php, laravel, api

When I call this API, I got this error "Property [date] does not exist on this collection instance."

This is my API code.

```
 public function apiGetAttend($id, Request $request)
    {
        $tokenuser = User::with('attendance')
            ->where('token', $request->input('token'))->first();
        $user = User::with('attendance')->find($id);

        if($user && $tokenuser == $user){
            return response()->json([
                'MacAddress' => $user->mac_address,
                'SerialNo'=>$user->serial_no,
                'Date' => $user->attendance->date,
                'Time' => $user->attendance->time,
                'Present' => $user->attendance->present
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Fail',
            'message' => 'You dont have access to see this user.'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: if `attendance` is a collection, you want the `date` property of one of the items it contains not the collection itself... were you not expecting `attendance` to be a collection (a many relation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since user has many attendancies, `$user->attendance` is a collection and not an object. So, you may want to iterate over it and all attendancies dates etc. Or you can use the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-first) collection method to get data from the first attendance in the collection:

```
'Date' => $user->attendance->first()->date,
'Time' => $user->attendance->first()->time,
'Present' => $user->attendance->first()->present
```

Comment: when i search on google, it said I need pivote table because of it is many to many relation between user and attendance table

Comment: when i use this code, it work but it doesnt show the latest attendance.

Comment: Okay now ! when i change 'first() to last()'. it shows the latest attendance of user.